# Node.js - SQL function doesn't return value

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, socket.io

i want to get a data from a MySQL database and i use Node.js with SQL for it, this is my server code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '127.0.0.1',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'temp'
});

function getData(res){
    var tempVal = 1377;
    connection.connect();
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM tempvalues ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1', function(err, rows){
        console.log(rows);
        tempVal = rows;
    });
    connection.end();
    return tempVal;
}

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('clientSent', function(data){
        if(data == "GET")
            socket.emit("serverSent", getData());
    })
})

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

If i go to `localhost:3000` i only get `1377` as value but not the actual value from the database, even though the console prints the correct values. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some things bad in your code.
First. Think that queries to database, in most of cases are asynchronous.

Your code explained :

```
function getData(res){
    var tempVal = 1377; // Create tempVal with 1377 as value initially.
    connection.connect(); // Connect to the database.
    // Run the query
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM tempvalues ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1', function(err, rows){
        // Here you are inside the callback executed asynchronously.
        console.log(rows);
        // You modify the top-level variable.
        tempVal = rows;
    });
    connection.end(); // End connection
    return tempVal; // You return 1377 since the callback is not yet finish and the value of tempVal not changed
}
```

One simple way to fight with async code are the callbacks. Let your getData function look like :

```
function getData(callback){
    var tempVal = 1377;
    connection.connect();
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM tempvalues ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1', function(err, rows){
        console.log(rows);
        return callback(err, rows);
    });
    connection.end();
}
```

Then use the function as follows:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('clientSent', function(data){
        if(data == "GET")
            getData(function(error, result){
              if(!error) socket.emit("serverSent", result);
            });
    })
});
```